# Keyerror on .format

Tags: python, floating-point, string-formatting

I am getting some sort of syntax error, that I need help understanding.

This is the code I have written -

```
offer=float(input("What's your offer"))
demand=float(500)
agree=offer+demand/2

print("You offer {f:0} " .format(offer) + "but the merchant wants {f:1} " .format(demand))
print("You finally agree on" + agree)
```

This is the error I receive -

```
File "c:\users\mariy\documents\visual studio 2013\Projects\PythonApplication4\PythonApplication4\module1.py", line 5, in <module>
print("You offer {f:0} " .format(offer) + "but the merchant wants {f:1} " .format(demand))
KeyError: 'f'
```

Answer (score 3):

`KeyError` is presenting itself because the format spec `{f:0}` tells `.format()` to look for a dict with key `f`, which isn't there.

Possibly, you want to use this:

```
print "You offer ${offer:6.2f} but the merchant wants ${demand:6.2f}".format(offer=200.0,demand=300.0)
```

You offer $200.00 but the merchant wants $300.00

You can replace the `200.0` and `300.0` by the variable names you want to use, and the `$` with some other currency symbol, or no symbol.

Notice the syntax:

1. the `$` is not part of the format syntax.  It is printed literally.
2. The formatting is done in curly braces, using `{keyname:spec}`
3. The `keyname` part is from a `kwargs` passed to `.format()`, i.e. if we have `{demand}` then we must have `.format(demand=something)` or `.format(somedict)` where `somedict` has `demand` as a key
4. The `spec` is where you put the number of digits, a dot, and the digits after the decimal point, and the variable type, as in `f` for floating point.  So `6.2f` means 6 digits wide total, 2 after the decimal point, floating point.

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to use the `.format()`, however the arguments inside `{}` referring to a `float` should be preceded by `:` and not otherwise.

The `0` and `1` will also cause some trouble during code execution, there is no need for them. However if you would like to use only one format operation, the numbers would be the indices of the tuple inside the `.format()`

ex: `"This is number {1} and this is {0}".format("zero", "one")` which would produce the following output `This is number one and this is zero`

The final print would also cause trouble since you cannot concatenate a string and a integer.

After some corrections, your code should look like this:

`print("You offer {:f} but the merchant wants {:f} ".format(offer, demand))
print("You finally agree on {:f}".format(agree))`

If you want to limit the number of decimal cases, you can define them in the `{}` arguments.

ex: `{:.2f}` will print the floating point number with 2 decimal cases